# NginX+Ubuntu+VirtualBox: How do I configure the local network for a new Nginx Server?

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, nginx

Following this tutorial: 
https://youtu.be/TIaBrUo2944

Of setting up a server using Nginx I encountered a few problems - guessing it's because it's not an actual server (I use Virtualbox).

1. I created a directory in /opt/www/cheqin.me
2. Added an index html file in this directory: index.html.
3. I created a new file in /etc/nginx/sites-available
4. `ln`ed it to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled successfully.

The content of this file is:

```
server {

    listen 80; 
    server_name www.cheqin.me; 
    access_log /opt/www/cheqin.me/access.log; 

    root /opt/www/cheqin.me;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

}
```

- As in the video, the dude runs www.cheqin.me in the URL bar and it works for him and displays the previously created index.html file content in the browser. 
  I just get this error: 
  Server not found

> Firefox can’t find the server at www.cheqin.me.
>
> ```
> Check the address for typing errors such as ww.example.com instead of www.example.com
> If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
> If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
> ```

- Running in the URL bar: `localhost/` works and displays the content from the default settings of Nginx (`/usr/shared/...`). "Welcome to nginx!"
- The same goes for 127.0.0.1
- Running http://localhost/index.html DOESN'T WORK.
- Running my IP on the URL bar (example: The IP in this website: www.whatismyip.com) just opens a login page of the security company of the internet network the office works on. So no access there.

R

Comment: did you install the nginx?

Comment: of course. All mentioned is after installing nginx. and tested `http://localhost/ `works well. @lewis4u

Comment: so you get the page that says nginx istalled successfully

Comment: @lewis4u yes. I think the problem is with setting hostnames (if needed in this case for 'cheqin.me' ?) or something with the network. I use windows and when running a weird URL like "www.cheqin.me" in the browser I get the exact same error.

Comment: try run this command `sudo nginx -t` if you don't get any errors on that command then your nginx server is fine and the problem is elsewhere

Comment: `root@ubuntest-VirtualBox:/usr/share/nginx/html# sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

Comment: OK, then check your privileges...maybe you don't have the rights....?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50441/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-rick-sanchez).